# Run over the row's of a csv data (in Python)

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop, row

I'm reading an csv - file with ten column's.

My formula should divide the first vector by the second vector. The first vector consists of the first five values (that means the first five column's of the exe data) and the second vector consists of the last five values (that means the last five column's of the exe data). 
Now I want to do a calculation over each row with the formula. That means, that I want to the calculation over the first row, the second row, the third row, and so on... with an output (a vector). 
For excample for the first row:

```
left = data_one.values[0,0:5]
right = data_one.values[0,5:10]
def symmetryRatio():
     result_one = left/right 
     print("The result is: " +str(result_one))
```

This is my example csv - Data with five row's (but I also can have a data with 100 or more row's):

1.00,0.80,0.40,0.20,0.50,1.20,0.90,0.30,0.20,0.34

1.10,0.85,0.50,0.21,0.59,1.30,0.95,0.40,0.21,0.42

0.90,0.90,0.45,0.23,0.50,1.10,1.00,0.35,0.23,0.35

1.05,0.70,0.40,0.28,0.57,1.25,0.80,0.30,0.28,0.38

0.95,0.75,0.45,0.30,0.60,1.15,0.85,0.35,0.30,0.42

I have already started with a new method which should run over each row:

```
data_one=pd.read_csv("file:///C:/Users/...../healthyValues.csv")
def rowPass():
    for line in data_one:
       print(line)
    return 0
```

And now I don't know how to go.

I hope it's clear what I want to do.

In the end there should be (I think so) two methods. One who is doing the calculation (symmetryRatio()) with the formula and one who run's over the row's (rowPass()).

Thanks for helping me.

**EDIT:**

Now I have calculated the mean average values over all colomns. Then I put these values in to two vectors. After that I used the formula for both vectors again.

```
one = data_one.iloc[:,0].mean()
two = data_one.iloc[:,1].mean()
three = data_one.iloc[:,2].mean()
four = data_one.iloc[:,3].mean()
five = data_one.iloc[:,4].mean()
six = data_one.iloc[:,5].mean()
seven = data_one.iloc[:,6].mean()
eight = data_one.iloc[:,7].mean()
nine = data_one.iloc[:,8].mean()
ten = data_one.iloc[:,9].mean()
#first vector:
 vek1=np.array([one1,two1,three1,four1,five1])
#second vector
 vek2=np.array([six1,seven1,eight1,nine1,ten1])
def symmetryRatio():
   res=vek1/vek2
   print(res)
```

In other words, I have two cases:

1. calculation over all rows (see GiovaniSalazar's correct answer)
2. Mean-Average-Value-Calculation over all colomns --> the first five values in one vector and the last five values in one vector (see my code)

Is there the opportunity to do this both things in one method or better in two? And how?

Comment: can you add how you expect the output ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry.
My output should show all results over the rows. 
So first the result of the first row with the formula, then over the second row, and so on...
You know how I mean it?

Comment: ok , but you have for example ...5 rows in your csv ....and symmetryRatio get 2 rows as input .....it repeat for each rows?...I mean symmetryRatio (row1,row2) symmetryRatio (row3,row4), symmetryRatio (row5,row6)....etc ?

Comment: or just the first and second rows ?

Comment: and also add your example csv like a text (I need copy) not like a image

Comment: No. My first vector consists of 5 values and the second too. These five values of the first vector are the first values of line one (that means that the first vector consists of the first value in line one, the second value of line one, the third value of line one, the fourth value of line one and the fifth value of line one).  The five values of second vector are the last five values of line one (that means that the first vector consists of the sixth value in line one, the seventh value of line one, the eighth value of line one, the ninth value of line one and the tenth value of line one).

Comment: I changed the image to text in my question.

Comment: symmetryRatio() get two vectors as input. This method should divide the both vectors

Comment: But symmetryRatio() should do this calculation for each row in the csv data. 
That means: The method should execute over the first row in the csv, then over the second row, and so on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with some like this ..with pandas (pip install pandas) and numpy  (pip install numpy  ):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

data = """
1.00,0.80,0.40,0.20,0.50,1.20,0.90,0.30,0.20,0.34
1.10,0.85,0.50,0.21,0.59,1.30,0.95,0.40,0.21,0.42
0.90,0.90,0.45,0.23,0.50,1.10,1.00,0.35,0.23,0.35
1.05,0.70,0.40,0.28,0.57,1.25,0.80,0.30,0.28,0.38
0.95,0.75,0.45,0.30,0.60,1.15,0.85,0.35,0.30,0.42
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',',header=None)
df1=df.to_numpy()

for line in df1:
  result_one = line[[0,1,2,3,4]]/line[[5,6,7,8,9]]
  print("The result is: " +str(result_one))
```

result:

```
The result is: [0.83333333 0.88888889 1.33333333 1.         1.47058824]
The result is: [0.84615385 0.89473684 1.25       1.         1.4047619 ]
The result is: [0.81818182 0.9        1.28571429 1.         1.42857143]
The result is: [0.84       0.875      1.33333333 1.         1.5       ]
The result is: [0.82608696 0.88235294 1.28571429 1.         1.42857143]
```

Comment: great @mathflower !

Comment: Could you check out the new edit in my question on the top, please?